# Addressing the cylinders of a Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive

I want to address the cylinders of a Hard Drive but I can't find a good manual of the pinout of the IDE interface. Anyone knows how to do that?

I don't want to read/write anything in the disk, just move the arm through the cylinders.
And I want to do that by connecting some wires on the interface and sending some signals.

Comment: How to you want to move the arm through the cylinders? mechanically or by software?

Comment: I want to connect some wires on the interface and send voltage signals to it using a microcontroller.

Comment: If you don't have any luck here, you might want to give the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) a try after you read their rules, of course.

Comment: As DS suggests, the relationship between physical cylinders and the wires in the IDE connector is somewhere between vague and mythical.  All modern drives contain an on-board microprocessor that does the real drive accessing.

Comment: (Maybe you should try playing "Anchors Aweigh" on a 1403 line printer.)

Answer (score 2):

A co-worker of mine was playing with a hack where he used stepper motors in old floppy drives to make music.. kind of fascinating.

I found a site on the basics of accessing the motors on floppies here:
http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/diskstepper.html

However, I feel it's unlikely that similar direct motor access is possible with IDE style drives... Modern (post MFM) hard drives have seriously abstracted control of the physical hardware from even the lowest level API calls. I"m not sure if what you want to do is possible, though it's something maybe you could email Steve Gibson at grc.com about.

Answer (score 2):

You can find something interesting e.g. in **Art of Assembly: Chapter Thirteen**

Following [13.2.5 INT 13h - Low Level Disk Services](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH13/CH13-2.html#HEADING2-73) you can think to use `int 13h`

> The int 13h function provides several different low-level disk services to PC programs: Reset the diskette system, get the diskette status, read diskette sectors, write diskette sectors, verify diskette sectors, and format a diskette track and many more.

From the section *Some Common Disk Subsystem BIOS Calls*:
AH= **0Ch**
Input Parameters: Same as (4) above except there is no need for a sector
Output Parameters: Same as (4) above    Sends the disk head to the specified track on the disk.
Description: **Sends the disk head to the specified track on the disk.**

For what it concern the IDE pinout... this is the 1st image that came out from google search ["IDE PINOUT"](http://bacman.co.uk/bacforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=3166):

[image]

Comment: What I want is connect some wires on these pins and send voltage signals to them using a microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE (really Parallel ATA) interface is well described in the Wikipedia article ("Parallel ATA"). From there you can find links to the actual specs. The older versions of the specs are all free for download (or were, the last time I checked).

DigitalSorceress is correct, though: There are no pins on the connector that will simply and directly tell the drive to move the arm. (Even a floppy drive interface isn't that easy.) The IDE drives were originally designed to connect directly to a 16-bit ISA bus in an IBM PC AT. The drive decodes a number of I/O "ports" that are addressable by the CPU. The drive interprets these as "registers". You load up various registers with the parameters for a command, then write a command to the command register. (You do that by speaking the ISA bus protocol to the pins on the IDE drive.) Then check status by reading back some of the same registers.

Two of the registers do specify the cylinder number, but just clocking a cylinder number into them isn't enough, nor is clocking a cylinder number into them just a matter of asserting some voltages on the pins.

If you were thinking of attaching the drive to an Arduino or something (it would have to be something like a Mega to get enough pins, I think), you could probably get the heads to move, with a considerable amount of programming. Remember in that case you'll not only be implementing the PATA protocol, you will also be running the ISA protocol in your code. That isn't terribly complicated, but it all adds up, and I don't know if an Arduino would be fast enough to meet the timing requirements on the bus.

It would be a lot easier to just connect the drive to an old PC. Then you could write a little assembly code to call INT functions out of the BIOS to access various blocks on the disk, as Hastur suggested.

Or you could connect it to a PATA-to-USB adapter and run it from a newer PC. It's not tough to write a program that talks to an unformatted hard drive (that is, one without a recognized file system).

Another complication is that we don't really address hard drives by cylinder/head/sector any more. We just use LBAs - logical block addresses. These start at 0 and go linearly up to n-1. The drive worries about how these map to C/H/S locations. This mapping is not straightforward because in modern drives the number of sectors per track changes from the outer cylinders to the  inner. I frankly don't know if modern drives can even take C/H/S addressing any more. Of course, if you just send the drive a series of increasing LBAs, the arm will move now and then when you happen to cross cylinder boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove (or bypassed) the IDE controller board from the drive itself you may be able to emulate the signals needed to position the arm with your microcontroller. It will be very dependent on the specific drive you are using, but would not be limited by the modern drive control abstractions. There may also be points exposed on the controller that could be "poked" to produce some interesting behaviors. Good luck. (:

[Western Digital IDE PCB Circuit Hard Drive Controller Board 2060-701596-001 RevA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG4Ao.png)